# Can I use a held spell as part of a full round attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, combat, touch-attacks

Say I am fighting a zombie with an oracle. I have a sword in one hand and have Cure Light Wounds in the other. Can I strike the Zombie with the sword then touch them with the Cure Light Wounds spell as a full round attack if I get 2 attacks as a full round action or do I lose the spell if I strike with the sword first?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, this works.**

It is not possible to apply the effects of your held spell using a weapon unless you have a suitable class feature such as the [Spellstrike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Spellstrike-Su-) ability from the Magus. There is no risk of the spell being lost just because you struck an opponent with the sword.

Further, touch spells can be [held as long as you like](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#holding-the-charge) until they are discharged or you cast another spell.

> If you don't discharge the spell in the round when you cast the spell,
> you can hold the charge indefinitely. You can continue to make touch
> attacks round after round. If you touch anything or anyone while
> holding a charge, even unintentionally, the spell discharges.

Whilst you are holding a spell charge any touch attacks made to apply the spell are considered to be armed. therefore you are currently considered to be armed with both hands.

> Touching an opponent with a touch spell is considered to be an armed
> attack and therefore does not provoke attacks of opportunity.

In the [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9onf) it is stated that you can make iterative attacks with different weapons without incurring any two weapon fighting penalties.

> **If I have extra attacks from a high BAB, can I make attacks with
> different weapons and not incur a two-weapon fighting penalty?**
>
> Yes. Basically, you only incur TWF penalties if you are trying to get an
> extra attack per round.

Therefore it is completely reasonable to use one hand to deliver the touch spell and the other to attack with a sword in the same full round provided you normally have two attacks.

Comment: I totally agree that this makes sense. Yes, a dude can, while wielding a longsword one-handed, cast with his empty hand *cure light wounds* then next round make a full attack that's first at his full base attack bonus with the longsword then at his base attack bonus −5 using the *cure light wounds* spell. However, the GM must agree that the things the caster is *already* touching (like the longsword) don't immediately blow the touch spell's charge. Yes, that *is* dumb, but there must be a reason for this [FAQ entry.](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qnr)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I disagree that the accidental discharge rule should ever be brought up in any situation. It was and is a terrible idea best ignored.

Comment: @KRyan I know, I know. We've discussed this. `:-)` Maybe you should pose a question and answer it so folks can clearly understand why? It'd make an awfully convenient link for questions like this.